# Do I need a visa to transit in Istanbul, Turkey?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, turkey, malaysian-citizens

I'm flying to Kuala Lumpur from Oslo with an 8-hour stopover in Istanbul on Turkish Airlines.

Do I need a visa if I want to leave the airport? I'm travelling on a Malaysian passport.

What would I be able to see or do in such a short time?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.kln.gov.my/web/tur_ankara/requirement_malaysians

> MALAYSIAN CITIZEN CAN ENTER TURKEY WITHOUT A VISA FOR THE PERIOD OF
>   STAY OF 90 DAYS(FOR SOCIAL VISIT ONLY) PROVIDED THAT THEIR PASSPORT
>   MUST BE VALID AT LEAST 6 MONTHS FROM THE DATE OF ENTRY. MALAYSIAN
>   CARRIED 'EMERGENCY CERTIFICATE (EC)' MUST OBTAINED A VISA AT TURKISH
>   EMBASSY IN KUALA LUMPUR.

http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa

> Malaysia: Ordinary and official passport holders are exempted from
>   visa for their travels up to 90 days.